# Why does my MS Access database crash every time I close a particular form?

Tags: database, forms, ms-access

My company uses a shared MS Access database and on the front end there is one particular button that causes the entire database to crash every time it is clicked. I've reviewed the code but can't quite figure out why it is crashing every time. The button is meant to save and close the form after creating a new record, and this is part of the code for the command to close:

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
    Forms!frmmenuPurchasing.Requery
    Forms!frmmenuPurchasing.Refresh
End Sub



Private Sub Close_Click()
On Error GoTo Close_Click_Err

    DoCmd.Close , ""

Close_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Close_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Close_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Does anyone see anything in this code that could be causing my database to crash when the form is closed? Any help is appreciated. TIA!

Comment: I am guessing by crash you mean access itself is hanging. If so, what you could do is add a breakpoint in your procedure, and click your button. Then you can `F8` step by step and see exactly where the crash occurs and take corrective measures. Just an idea. :)

Comment: What is `frmmenuPurchasing`?  Is that the form you're attempting to close via that close button?

Comment: @HansUp Yes that is the form name that I'm attempting to save and close.

Comment: Then if you disable or remove the `Requery` and `Refresh` lines from `Form_Close`, does the form close cleanly?

Comment: @HansUp No it does not :( I also get an error message that says "Can't find the database you specified, or you didn't specify a database at all. Specify a valid database name in the command line, and include a path if necessary" whenever I try to open it back up (in the rare cases that it doesn't crash).

Comment: Hello @lg_5213! Did you ever find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that when you say "shared" that you mean your Access application uses another Access application as Library/Dll....   well is a bad practice and it causes issues..
Start by decompiling everything and check for missing/broken references.
Also a good crashing candidate is ActiveX that are manipulate a bit out of the ordinary ...and last but not least...you could have some design fault in your code...like opening Recordsets and not closing or bad implementation...(this is tricky)